# Phone tried to create a new work profile when one existed, and now says account action required

Tags: google-play-services, profiles, work-profiles

I've had a work profile setup and working flawlessly for a year or so using my work e-mail. Yesterday I realized I had been signed out of my work's Slack which was not installed on my work profile but had worked fine until the last week or so.

I attempted to sign back into slack and it seemed like Google was attempting to create a new work profile for my existing work e-mail, and I was unable to auth properly so the sign-in failed. I stopped the process, uninstalled Slack, reinstalled it on my work profile, signed in and everything seemed fine.

The problem I'm having now is that every hour I get a notification ding that "Account action required" for my work e-mail account. Clicking on that gives me a notice that says "Can't add work profile". After clicking on it, the notification disappears and then I get notified again a minute later.

Things I've Tried:

- Turning off, waiting, and turning back on notifications for Google Play Services
- Rebooting
- Clearing Google Play Services cache

All give me the notification within 30 seconds after completion. It seems like a bad idea to permanently disable notifications for Google Play Services, so I'm hoping for a less drastic option that also doesn't require deleting my existing work profile.

Any ideas for how I can stop being constantly bugged by this notification?

Comment: I was unable to come to a solution, so for now I've just disabled notifications from Google Play Services. This seems like a bad idea, but I don't think I've got any better options at the moment.